# How to fix the error on java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4 >= 4

Tags: java, mysql

My program is used to display the textfield values and date to a table in java and saves the table value to MySQL database. The textfiled and dateChooser data is displayed in the table and saved in one click of a button

```
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable2.getModel();
    model.addRow(new Object[]
            {((JTextField) invo_date.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText(),
                    ((JTextField) invo_date1.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText(),
                    dec.getText(), BL.getText()});

    conn = JavaDb.ConnectDB();
    int p = 0;
    if (p == 0) {
        try {
            int rows = jTable2.getRowCount();
            String queryco = "update into status(date, to_date, description, containers) values( ?,?,?,?)"; 

            pst = conn.prepareStatement(queryco);
            for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {

                String datee = (String) jTable2.getValueAt(row, 0);
                String mpakadates = (String) jTable2.getValueAt(row, 1);
                String descri = (String) jTable2.getValueAt(row, 2);
                String total = (String) jTable2.getValueAt(row, 3);
                String container = (String) jTable2.getValueAt(row, 4);

                pst.setString(1, datee);
                pst.setString(2, mpakadates);
                pst.setString(3, descri);
                pst.setString(4, total);
                pst.setString(5, container);
                pst.addBatch();
            }
            pst.executeBatch();
            pst.execute();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Data Saved Successfully");
            st.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Got an exception! " + e);
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: First at all, code `int p = 0; if (p == 0)` looks strange. Second - what line produce index exception?

Comment: question is not so clear, please add exception message. It seems some problem with jTable

Comment: Check your query, you have 4 `?` params, but trying to send 5.

Comment: need something like String queryco = "update into 
    status(date,to_date,description,total,containers)values(?,?,?,?,?)";

Comment: @BorLaze the p = 0 is used to prompt the user if he/she wishes to save

Comment: Well, your table contains rows with four columns, yet you are trying to get five values from each row. That is what causes an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.